# Line up a form_for button in a bootstrap btn-group in rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button created using form_for

```
<%= form_for(current_user.likes.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
<div><%= hidden_field_tag :post_id, post.id %></div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
    <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> Like
</button>
<% end %>
```

I'd like it to be one of the buttons in a bootstrap btn-group:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
        <%= form_for(current_user.likes.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
        <div><%= hidden_field_tag :post_id, post.id %></div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
            <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> Like
        </button>
        <% end %>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Middle</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Right</button>
    </div>
```

The problem is it looks like this:

[image]

Instead of everything being straight across like this:

[image]

I think the `<form>` is being forced on it's own line.  I tried using form_tag and button_for, but both create a `<form>` which ends up having the same issue.  How can I get the same functionality of calling the controller remote and passing a variable but have it line up properly?

Here is the final output of HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
                <form class="new_like" id="new_like" action="/likes" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="tlp7nQs9rmJiZz/OnRQXeYa6sFlZmWKlf4OUwfbI1YALdg==">
                <div><input type="hidden" name="post" id="post_id" value="311"></div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">
                    <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i> Like
                </button>
</form>           
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Middle</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Right</button>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2y7zunqg/

Comment: how does the final HTML look like?

Comment: @Aziz I've just added the HTML

Comment: yeah.. I believe all the buttons should be INSIDE the form, can you do that?

Comment: @Aziz no I can't because if I do the links will not route to the correct controller

Comment: Do they even work when you click on them?

Comment: @Aziz no they do not if I wrap them in the form tags.  Otherwise they work fine. I should be clear: I don't really have  "Middle" and "Right" I have other buttons but I just didn't include them as I didn't think it was relevant.  They are buttons made with link_to helper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is only to make it look like the normal button group from bootstrap you can do something like

```
.btn-group form{
  float:left; 
  display: inline;// no needed as pointed by Aziz
}

.btn-group form .btn{
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

If you put each button inside other forms then you will have to use `:first-child` and `:last-child` selectors to use the same style bootstrap uses.

What I basically did was to go [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups) and right on one of the buttons and click Inspect then see the style each class applies.

Comment: This works, tho `display:inline;` might not be needed

Comment: it is needed since the browser default display for a form tag is `block` (at least on chrome)

Comment: Actually you are right. The float left seems to be enough since in doesn't care about the display value. Thanks for pointing it out